# What does the "Enable Glow Effect" checkbox do?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I'm about to render a replay, and amongst the advanced options in the modal dialog there is a checkbox to "Enable Glow Effect".

What is this, and what effects will it have on my replay if I enable it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 3 glow effects in the game.

1. As a demoman, any stickybombs you place glow.
2. In Payload maps, the bomb cart glows.
3. In CTF maps, the intelligence briefcases glow.

Glows are visible through walls.

I assume that enabling this (it's disabled by default) will show any glows you would normally see.

It's not useful most of the time, unless you were recording a replay of a demoman life.

Comment: Don't only ScoRes stickybombs glow like the payload and intel, though? Or are you referring to the pulses emitted by all stickybombs?

Comment: @TheAnnoyingPyro: I'm not sure.  I thought normal sticky bombs glowed too for the last few months, though.  Maybe not.